# Comparing Pivot Tables in Java

Tags: java, excel, pivot-table

I have an Excel file. In sheet one, I have a bunch of different parts and their corresponding weights and what their part category is. In sheet two, I have the same thing, but the weights might have changed. I am trying to find the difference in the total weight of each category between the two sheets. To do this, I made two pivot table objects grouping the weights by part category. Now I want to find the difference in the weights. Is there a way to index pivot table objects so I can iterate through the pivot table and calculate the difference? I am unable to find any documentation on this issue.

```
        FileInputStream input_document = new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\Tests\\Demo Data.xlsx"));   
        XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(input_document); 
        XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0); 
        XSSFSheet sheetTwo = workbook.getSheetAt(1);
        AreaReference a = new AreaReference("A1:F2376");
        CellReference b = new CellReference("I1");
        AreaReference c = new AreaReference("A1:F2376");
        CellReference d = new CellReference("I1");
        XSSFPivotTable pivotTable = sheet.createPivotTable(a, b);
        pivotTable.addRowLabel(0);
        pivotTable.addRowLabel(1);
        pivotTable.addColumnLabel(DataConsolidateFunction.SUM, 5);
        XSSFPivotTable legacyPivot = sheetTwo.createPivotTable(c, d);
        legacyPivot.addRowLabel(0);
        legacyPivot.addRowLabel(1);
        legacyPivot.addColumnLabel(DataConsolidateFunction.SUM, 5);

        FileOutputStream output_file = new FileOutputStream("C:\\Tests\\Demo Data.xlsx"); 
        workbook.write(output_file);


        ArrayList<Double> values = new ArrayList<Double>();
        for(Row r : sheet) {
           Cell cell = r.getCell(9);
           if(cell != null) {
              if(cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC) {
                  System.out.println(cell.getNumericCellValue());
                 values.add(cell.getNumericCellValue());
              } else if(cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA && cell.getCachedFormulaResultType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC) {
                  System.out.println(cell.getNumericCellValue());
                  values.add(cell.getNumericCellValue());
              }
           }
        }
```

Above is what I tried. I thought I could store the column values in a list for both pivot tables and then iterate through the lists and calculate the difference. However, I am getting an output of a blank list when I tried to do it with the first pivot table.

Comment: what did you try?

Comment: You should add some code to make your question more intuitive.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please take a moment to review the tour: https://stackoverflow.com/tour , 
How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve , and more specifically, 
*How to Ask Good Questions* https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask 
- you'll get better feedback and helpful answers if you put some thought in to your problem before coming to SO for help, and by including a specific problem with code *that you've tried* showing effort to solve the problem yourself.

Comment: [Please avoid posting code in the form of screenshots.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3775798) They're harder to read and search, and become useless if the link goes down. Edit your post again and include the code as [formatted text](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code).